# get_dummies for Pandas column containing list

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Given I have a DataFrame with a column that contains lists of strings, like this:

```
    Name    Fruit
0   Curly   [Apple]
1   Moe     [Orange]
2   Larry   [Apple, Banana]
```

How would I turn that into something like this?

```
    Name     Fruit_Apple   Fruit_Orange   Fruit_Banana
0   Curly              1              0              0
1   Moe                0              1              0
2   Larry              1              0              1
```

I have a feeling I'd somehow use `pandas.get_dummies()` but I can't seem to get it. Any help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name': ['Curly', 'Moe', 'Larry'],
                   'Fruit': [['Apple'], ['Orange'], ['Apple', 'Banana']]},
                  columns=['Name', 'Fruit'])

# a one-liner... that's pretty long    
dummies_df = pd.get_dummies(
  df.join(pd.Series(df['Fruit'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True),
                    name='Fruit1')).drop('Fruit', axis=1).rename(columns={'Fruit1': 'Fruit'}),
  columns=['Fruit']).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()

print(dummies_df)
```

I'll break this down into steps:

**Step 1:**

`df['Fruit'].apply(pd.Series).stack().reset_index(1, drop=True)`

This step applies `pd.Series` to your lists which splits each item in your lists to a new column. `stack` then stacks these columns into one single column while maintaining important index info. The `reset_index` part resets level 1 of the index and drops it because it's not needed. You end up with this:

```
0     Apple
1    Orange
2     Apple
2    Banana
dtype: object
```

**Step 2:**

You'll notice `pd.Series( *Step 1 here*, name='Fruit1')` is wrapped around Step 1 code above because we will next join this series to the existing dataframe so we need a `name` in order to do that.

**Step 3:**

```
df.join(* steps 1 and 2 code *).drop('Fruit', axis=1).rename(columns={'Fruit1': 'Fruit'})
```

Since we now have a `pd.Series` with a name (`Fruit1`), we join the `Fruit1` series to the original `df` which then has three columns.  We then call drop to drop the original `Fruit` column. Now we just have two columns `Name` and `Fruit1` but we want `Fruit` to be named `Fruit` so we rename it with `rename`.

**Step 4:**

```
pd.get_dummies(* steps 1, 2, and 3 here*, columns=['Fruit'])
```

Here, we finally call the `get_dummies` and we use the `columns=['Fruit']` to specifically tell get_dummies to only get dummies for the Fruit column.

```
    Name  Fruit_Apple  Fruit_Banana  Fruit_Orange
0  Curly          1.0           0.0           0.0
1    Moe          0.0           0.0           1.0
2  Larry          1.0           0.0           0.0
2  Larry          0.0           1.0           0.0
```

**Step 5:**

```
dummies_df = (*steps 1, 2, 3, and 4*).groupby('Name', as_index=False).sum()
```

Lastly you use a `groupby` on the `Name` column and specify `as_index=False` to optionally not set the `Name` as the index.  Then sum that result with `.sum()`

**Final result**:

```
    Name  Fruit_Apple  Fruit_Banana  Fruit_Orange
0  Curly          1.0           0.0           0.0
1  Larry          1.0           1.0           0.0
2    Moe          0.0           0.0           1.0
```

Comment: You can replace Step 4 and 5 with pd.crosstab(df_unwind['Name'], df_unwind['Fruit1']). df_unwind is the df after Step 3. Ther's not one-liner but shorter.